# Compile a programming language with itself

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

I'm a computer science student. I want to create my own programming language (A basic language with few instructions).

I know how to do a syntactic analyser, I already did it in Perl. In an article, I read something about the compiler, a compiler is done in itself.

For example the C compiler is written in C. How it's possible?
I can make my own language but I don't know how I could execute it? Any idea?

It's really a good question and I can write a blog the project.

Comment: People have explained how to bootstrap but why do you need to? There's no reason you can't compile your language using a compiler written in C, Perl or anything else. Sure, it would be nice to have a compiler for your language written in itself but that would be a lot of work -- you'd have to write at least two compilers to get that (one in C/Perl/whatever, one in your language).

Comment: Hmm.. I think I will write my first compiler in C and write a seconde in my language.
It's really interesting to create a little programming language, we can learn a lot of the computer science

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is *bootstrapping*. You first write a compiler for your language (or a subset thereof) in some other language. Then you write a compiler for your language (or a large subset of the one you can already handle) in your language. You use the former compiler to compile the new compiler, and then the new compiler can compile itself.

Comment: So, I can create my first compiler using C and next time I will compile my compiler v2 with the v1 ?
But there is a problem, how could I know the compiler doesn't have any problem ?
I need to convert my source code to assembler ? Or in other thing ?

Comment: *How could I know the compiler doesn't have any problem?* More generally, you wrote a program; how do you know it has no bugs? You don't. You write some tests and hope for the best. *Do I need to convert my source code to assembly?* Definitely not. You can trust the C compiler. You are doing the same thing, but with assembly replaced with C (or any other language of your choice).

Comment: Okay I have to trust in my skills ^^
I wanted to ask the process do the compiler. I really don't understand what a compiler do, syntaxic and lexical analyzer okay but next ??

Comment: Then you generate code. If you don't want to get into the details of generating machine code, you can always generate code in some other language, say C code, and use an external compiler to compile that into machine code. (Or you could use an interpreted language and run an interpreter.)

Comment: Hummm No I prefere do it like that : My Language in enter --> Machine Code.
I don't want to convert my language in another (same for first time compile)
It is possible ?

Comment: Of course it's possible, any of the compilers you use do it. It's just more complicated. You can try adding your language as a front-end for GCC (which has back-ends outputting machine code), but then the compiler would have to interface with C code. One reason for not outputting machine code is that machine code depends on the machine - it's not portable.

Comment: Why compiler would have to interface with C code ? And I can't create a programming language portable ?

Comment: If you want to interface with GCC, you need to interface with C code, since GCC is written in C. Programming languages are inherently portable, but there are no portable compilers. You need a different compiler for each system. There are ways around it - compile to another language or to a virtual machine (such as JVM), and interface to a portable compiler like GCC that knows how to handle many different computer systems.

Comment: So, if I use GCC to create my own compiler, did this compiler could be a little bit portable ? Or I need a version for each OS ?

Comment: That depends on your code. GCC itself is quite portable.

Comment: okay, I just want to make a langage which regonize some basic math function (sum, etc..) SO I can use GCC for my first compiler. I have to traduce my language in C with my compiler ? First I use lexical and syntaxical analyzer to verify my code and after ? This is the thing I don't understand. What do the next step ?

Comment: GCC is composed of two parts: front-ends and back-ends. The front-ends handle different programming languages, and the back-ends do code generation. I suggest you read the documentation of GCC if you want to go this way. If you don't have much programming experience, you can delay this experiment for later, and focus for now on programming *something* that works.

Comment: Hum okay, I will read it. I can make a program which convert my language into C really easily. But write a compiler I can't. Any link where I can learn the last step of a compiler ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such link, unfortunately.

Comment: A real-world example of this would be Microsoft's Visual Studio, where each new version is compiled with the previous version.  I believe GCC and Clang are the same, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

A compiler which can compile its own sources is called a [self-hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting) compiler. Early compilers were written in another language.
For example, the first C compiler was probably written in assembler.
The whole trick in using a former lower level compiler is called bootstrapping.